# Disable logging of Exception in Bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy, wildfly-10

I'm using Wildfly 10 and JAX-RS (resteasy) and have a Bean being injected in another Bean:

```java
@Path("foo")
public class FooResource {
    @Inject
    BarBean bar;
    ...
}
```

Then I'm calling a method on `bar` that throws a RuntimeException. I'm handling this Exception in `FooResource`, but Wildfly has interceptors that print the stack trace to the log. I don't want this to happen. Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Comment: Is BarBean an EJB?

Answer (score 0):

I could only reproduce this when the `@Inject`ed bean was a EJB (with Wildfly-9).

You can disable EJB exception logging through the webinterface (:9990)

Configuration -> Subsystems -> EJB 3 -> Log system exceptions
Put this value to false and you should not see exceptions logged anymore.